# How to make Eclipse package ONLY required libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

After developing a java app in Eclipse, I would like to deploy it by packaging it into a runnable `.jar` with **only** the minimum necessary by the main method and its dependencies.

I have several packages in my workspace I work with too, but do not need to be in the resulting `.jar` file.

[image: Eclipse exportation snapshot]

When I try to export, it clearly says that the required libs will be there, but also the other independent packages are inside too. (With the Export option happen exactly the same)

[image: Package view snapshot]

I choose to export only the Main class of the `com.project...` package, but also the `test.project...` has been packaged.

In the project I have both `com...` and `test...` packages obviously.

How could I force it to truly package **only** the required ones?

Thanks in advance.

#### TEMPORARY ANSWER (2019-07-03):

Seems that, for now, there is no way to achieve this automatically, thus [the answer from @arnonuem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56831145/5162745) seems a good workaround.

If better news, please feel free to improve this thread.

Thank you all.

Comment: Switch to intelliJ, this is one of the reasons I did. 
The only way I was able to do what you are trying to do in eclipse, was manually select everything I wanted before building code. 
If you are trying to get the packages from jar files, you're better off taking what you need from them manually, and packaging them up yourself into a dependency jar file, or into your release build.

Comment: What is your source structure? Where does `test` come from? Is it in a separate project or in the same? In other words: Do you need to exclude projects or something inside a project?

Comment: @Joe I have tried IntelliJ several times and it does not fit with my workflow, this is one of the few things I found annoying in Eclipse, I do not think that is reason enough to switch.

Comment: @Izruo While I do not "need", I would like to. As I said, I have multiple packages inside the project, but only want to export the minimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create an ANT file for this specific task. There you can freely customize which packages should be compiled into the jar and which not.
Please inspire yourself reading this example.

For a general overview what i am talking about you could take a quick look into this.
https://howtodoinjava.com/ant/ant-build-jar-file-example/

Please focus on

```xml
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="classpath"
        includes="src/path/to/TheClassToBeIncluded.java" />
```

For more detailed information on how to include or exclude files or packages you should refer to the documentation over here:

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

At the bottom of this page there is a list with valid build parameters.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and welcome to StackOverflow. What I would like to do is to make Eclipse be able to auto-recognize necessary dependencies and extract and compile only those ones. If I would have to do that manually, by removing the undesired package after exporting should be enough. I can even automate that with bash/python/whatever, but that is not the point.

Comment: @DavidTaberneroM Eclipse cannot recognize any dependencies; either you or the packages itself has to declare them (therefore java9 modules might work, but I have never looked into it). However, this is one way of doing it, my answer is just another, albeit more interface-oriented.

Comment: @arnonuem I can't associate the link with the example you provided. Could you please provide a more exact link or describe how I can find documentation about the `includes` attribute on that website? For example: does it support pattern matches?

Comment: Now I am starting to look forward to this as the potential solution if there is no better thing.

Comment: @Izruo Thank you for the info. I just updated the answer a little bit. When i find more time i could also imagine to add an example to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we have to distinguish build and export.

*Build* transfers `.java` source code into `.class` byte code and mostly copies other resources. While doing that it usually merges all source folders into a single `bin` folder.

*Export* runs a build (or relies on *Build Automatically*) and then modifies the resulting `.class` files and other resources. Usually it packages them into one or more `.jar` files.

Therefore, our solution includes two steps:

1. build everything that is unwanted for export into a separate folder (or more)
2. export from a specific folder (or more)

For step 1, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10174378/7525132) on Stack Overflow.

In a nutshell: Go to `Project Properties` > `Java Build Path` > `Source` tab > `Allow output folder for source folders`. This enables you to configure a specific output folder for each source folder in the centered viewer.

For step 2, we need to understand that eclipse's *Runnable Jar File Export* relies on a *Launch Configuration*.

So before exporting, go to `Run` > `Run Configurations...`, select the `Classpath` tab, remove the default `User Entries` and hit `Advanced...`. Now you can `Add Folders` containing your built classes.

You might want to use separate Run Configurations for internal testing and exporting.

Comment: I see, so I am starting to think there is no way I could do all of this automatically with Eclipse. Thanks for the references anyway, will check them out.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this problem on and off for years, supposing it was just me who was failing to find the right solution. Possible solutions always seem to involve detailed manual configuration e.g. configuration of the build path, or selection of the folders from which classes are exported into a jar, or learning ant, but which still requires manual configuration. The problem is that the inter-dependencies between classes (and packages) are complex - imagine drawing a network diagram from import statements. Manual configuration is time-consuming, error-prone and, I think, infeasible except in simple cases. I am a bit stunned. If there is no automatic solution for selecting necessary classes, I suppose people are regularly exporting their entire code base and that the world is full of bloated jars ... (and, incidentally, without obfuscation, the entire source code base is thereby made available through reverse engineering).

Comment: Reverse engineering dependencies from `import` statements might not be sufficient, because many programs use *service provider* patterns. In such a case, only an interface is required to successfully compile the code, whereas the actual implementation will be determined later at runtime. If a program uses this pattern internally, hence its provides both the interface and the implementation, e.g. to separate modules, such a dependency will not be recognized.